# Format String to truncate a number to a specific number of digits

Tags: truncate, digits, format-string

Is there a format string to truncate a number to a specific number of digits?
For example,  any number greater than 5 digits i would like to truncate to 3 digits.

```
132456 -> 132
5000000 -> 500
```

@Erik : Format specifiers like %2d are specific to a language? I actually want to use it in javascript

Comment: Probably. First of all, you should tell us the language you are working with. The String class is not the same for all programming languages, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-Code

```
Function returning a String, receiving a String representing a Number as a parameter
    IF the String has more than 5 characters
        RETURN a substring containing the first 3 characters.
    ELSE
        RETURN the string received as a parameter
    END IF
END Function
```

Comment: Im looking for a format-string and not code to truncate the number of digits.Looks like it doesnt exist?

Comment: I am sorry. I never heard of what is a "format-string" before. Please ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you refer to `printf` format strings. I couldn't find anything that will truncate an integer argument (i.e. `%d`). But you can specify the maximum length of a string by referring to a string format string and specifying lengths via `"%<MinLength>.<MaxLength>s"`.
So in your case you could turn your number arguments into strings and then use `"%3.3s"`.